# Push from Tab Bar Controller to a new Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have a `UITableView` on a Tab Bar page. Now I want to push to a new Tab Bar Controller if I tap on a `UITableViewCell`.

My storyboard looks something like this right now:
[image: TabBarPush]

My problem is when I tap on the cell, it opens the new page (the top right Controller in the picture), but the TabBar is still the same as before and the navigation bar title is empty even if I set one (`self.title = @"Test";`)

Here is some code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue" sender:self.view];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        self.myTabbarController = (UITabBarController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        self.topRightController = [self.myTabbarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        self.topRightController.value = [Values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Can someone help me out with this problem?

Comment: @danh It's a push segue, because I want to get back to the first TabBarController after pushing to the second one

Comment: if your'e using only one tab in first tabbarcontroller why to take it as a tabbar controller

Comment: @sreekanthk .. it's just a demo. My actual storyboard is way bigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem. I changed my storyboard to something like this (Not my actual storyboard):

[image: SolvedPicture]

I don't use a push segue anymore. I use a modal segue now. I use a own Back-Button to get back to the first Tab Bar Controller.

Here is the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` Method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITabBarController *tab = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newTabBarController"];

        self.myNavController = [tab.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        self.topRightController = [self.myNavController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        self.topRightController.value = [Values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self presentViewController:tab animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me. How to add a back button to the presented controller ? I tried adding custom button but its not showing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the push segue is a push in the context of the navigation controller, that happens *inside* the existing tab bar controller.  To get the effect you want, make it a modal presentation, roll your own back button on the (new) navigation controller that get's presented.  That button's action will be a dismissViewController.

Another alternative would be to leave your nav controller alone and modify the tab bar based on what's pushed.  (which alternative to use depends on the app semantics).  That's tricky, too, because you need to get at the containing tab bar vc via the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a delegate method and implement that in the class that creates your first `UITabBarController`, you can then create the new `UITabBarController` there.

You'll need to implement `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to call the delegate method, which will then create and display the new `UITabBarController` in the same way you displayed the first one.

If you want to have a back button from the new `UITabBarController` to the original one, you'll need to manually add that to the new controller, because default back buttons are handled automatically and only exist within each `UINavigationController`.